# Issue with Data Mapper And Sinatra in Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper, require

I am sure this is a simple issue but since I have looked so long I cannot see it. So I am running ruby 1.9.3 with Sinatra, sqlite3, datamapper, dm-sqlite-adapter. When I try to run Sinatra, I get this:

```
/Users/XXX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- datamapper (LoadError)
from /Users/XXX/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from app.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Here are the first two lines:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'datamapper'
```

The gem is installed. (datamapper (1.2.0))

Comment: Are you using Bundler? RVM?

Comment: Then I'd suggest create a new gemset just for this project, and then installing the gems again into it and see if you still get the problem. If you decide to use Bundler (which I think is better at gem management, RVM for management of rubies) then try `bundle install --binstubs --path vendor` to sandbox the gems, then try running via `bundle exec ruby app.rb` or `bin/rackup config.ru` (whichever fits best).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to require `data_mapper`, not `datamapper` (note the underscore):

```
require 'data_mapper'
```

See the [DataMapper getting started page](http://datamapper.org/getting-started.html).